# Java EE Login Page Problem

Tags: java, servlets, authentication

i try to code a login form which passes username and password to a servlet and let the user login.

Then, in the servlet, i lo

```
request.login(username, password);
```

but it throws exception which failed to authenticate the user.

```
String authType = request.getAuthType();
if(authType != null) {
request.login(username, password);
}
```

1. I wonder how to code a simple login page.
2. What is the uses of request.authenticate(response);

I try that and it pop out a screen which cannot be proceed anymore.

1. I try to refer this page http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security5.html which i think need to configure the authentication first before login and add some user.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method indicates that you're using Servlet 3.0 which is part of Java EE 6. Yet you're reading a 7.5 years old J2EE 1.4 tutorial. I'd suggest to put that dusty tutorial aside and read the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) instead. Container managed security starts [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html).

Back to your concrete problem, the `login()` will ([as documented](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) throw an exception when the login is invalid or when the container doesn't have any *Realm* definied at all. Assuming that you're certain that the username/password is valid, it'll probably be the last cause. How to do it exactly depends on the servletcontainer in question. Just consult its documentation using the keyword "Realm". For example, for Tomcat 7.0 that's the [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html). If you have the usernames/passwords in a SQL database, you'll probably want to use the [JDBCRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm).

Once you've configured a *Realm* at servletcontainer level, then you'll be able to use the `login()` method the way you want. Don't forget to add a `<security-constraint>` to the `web.xml` as per the Java EE 6 tutorial to restrict access on certain URL patterns and specify the URL of the login page.

Comment: How to configure realm servlet container level with glassfish ?

Comment: You're welcome. In Glassfish you can configure it in the *Configuration > Security > Realms* section of the admin console. You can find here a neat blog which outlines how to configure a JDBCRealm (with a JDBC connection pool for MySQL): https://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/5522-Configuring-Security-in-Glassfish-v3.html

Comment: So far, i know how to configure the JDBC realam but how to code the jdbc realm using java ee 6 ? Thanks for your help.