# Programmatically control login with Servlet 3.0

Tags: jsf, servlets, servlet-filters

I've tested the default security containers in Glassfish 3.0.1 and come to the conclusion that I won't spend any more time on that. Instead I want to control the verification myself. But I need some guidance to get me on right track.

At the moment I have a UserBean that has a login/logout function (see below). And I don't want to use the *j_security_check* built in container, but use core JSF 2.0.

My questions are;

1. Do I need a ServletFilter to redirect traffic if the user is not logged in (if accessing certain folders)?
2. How do I store User Pricipals after the user successfully logged in ?

Appreciate any help or link to a example, greetings Chris.

PS. Excuse me for clustering two questions together

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

private AuthenticateUser authenticateUser;
...

public String login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    JsfUtil.log("Username : " +authenticateUser.getUserName());
    JsfUtil.log("Password : " +authenticateUser.getPassword());
    AuthenticateUser authRequest = authenticationFacade.find(authenticateUser);
    try {
        if(!authRequest.equals(authenticateUser))
            return "/loginError";

        request.login(authenticateUser.getUserName(), authenticateUser.getPassword());
        return "";
    } catch(ServletException e){
       JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Incorrect username or password, please try again.");
       return "/loginError";
    }

...
public String logOut() {
    String result = "/index?faces-redirect=true";
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        request.logout();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        JsfUtil.log("Failed to logout user!" +e.getRootCause().toString());
        result = "/loginError?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to utilize `request.login()`, then you should really have configured a Realm in the container which represents the user database. But you seem to have replaced the Realm by some `AuthenticationFacade`. In this case, the `request.login()` is not useful for you.

You need to just put the user in the session scope and intercept on that. Here's a kickoff example:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserManager {

    @EJB
    private UserService userService;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private User current;

    public String login() {
        current = userService.find(username, password);

        if (current == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Unknown login, try again"));
            return null;
        } else {
            return "userhome?faces-redirect=true";
        }
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "index?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return current != null;
    }

    // Getters/setters (but do NOT provide a setter for current!)
}
```

When taking authentication in hands like this, then you definitely need a [filter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to restrict access. When using container managed security you would typically specify it as `<url-pattern>` of `<security-constraint>` for this. But without it, you've to take it in your hands. It's good to know that JSF managed beans are keyed by their managed bean name in any scope.

```
UserManager userManager = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("userManager");

if (userManager == null || !userManager.isLoggedIn()) {
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("login.xhtml");
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Map the above filter on the desired URL-pattern.

---

When you still want to reconsider using container managed authentication, then the following related answers may be useful:

- [Java EE Login Page Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079469/java-ee-login-page-problem/6079648#6079648) (and [Configuring Realm in Glassfish](https://www.infosecisland.com/blogview/5522-Configuring-Security-in-Glassfish-v3.html))
- [Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF using j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147)

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. Maybe it not wise to not use a realm from the app container. But I stumbled on patrol, when I tried to use my table structure/design. It's felt to much of a black box with the container realm. But with the ServletFilter I can still restrict all access to the root and other folders. So I give that a try tomorrow. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware if you are if you are using JDBC realm security. There are some fixed/expected words in the fields where you configure the realm in the Glassfish admin console.

In the **JAAS Context:** filed, you have to type: *jdbcRealm*. This keyword makes the security container use the expected JDBC realm. If you type something else, it won't work.

Here is good example, done by Gordan Jugo; [Netbeans/Glassfish JDBC Security Realm](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html)