# How control access and rights in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, servlet-filters, login-control

I would like to control the access after the user log in my system.

For example:

```
administrator : can add, delete and give rights to employee
employee : fill forms only
...
```

So after knowing which right the user has, checking in database, I would like to restrict what this user can see and do.
There's a simple way to do that ?

**EDIT**

```
@WebFilter("/integra/user/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {    
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Authorization authorization = (Authorization) req.getSession().getAttribute("authorization");

        if (authorization != null && authorization.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is logged in, so just continue request.
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // User is not logged in, so redirect to index.
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/integra/login.xhtml");
        }
    }

    // You need to override init() and destroy() as well, but they can be kept empty.


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you authenticating the users? By container managed authentication (`j_security_check` or `request.login()`) or by a homebrewed servlet filter on a session attribute?

Comment: @BalusC,Hello my friend! Long time no talk with you.
I'm using a servlet filter that you teach me a long time ago, which I'm gonna post it here.

Comment: You could check out http://jguard.sourceforge.net/mvnsite/docbook/en_jGuard_reference.html#d108e3815 We had to create a custom EL function to check if a user has a certain role though (to use in rendered attributes for example)

Comment: I'm quite curious about this myself. Can't really recall the scope of seam 3 security nor similar concepts in codi but they may be useful. Deltaspike will add this for v 0.4 (the next one) iirc.

I have also peeked at apache shiro but decided against it. I have decided to halt my auth logic for now and wait for v.04 of deltaspike

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, this is a pretty broad subject. As you're starting off with homebrewed authentication, I'll target the answer on homebrewed authorization.

---

Role checking in Java/JSF is at its own relatively simple if the model is sensibly designed. Assuming that a single user can have multiple roles (as is often the case in real world applications), you'd ultimately like to end up having something like:

```
public class User {

    private List<Role> roles;

    // ...

    public boolean hasRole(Role role) {
        return roles.contains(role);
    }

}
```

```java
public enum Role {

    EMPLOYEE, MANAGER, ADMIN;

}
```

so that you can check it as follows in your JSF views:

```html
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{user.roles}" disabled="#{not user.hasRole('ADMIN')}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{Role}" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

```html
<h:commandButton value="Delete" rendered="#{user.hasRole('ADMIN')}" />
```

and in your filter:

```java
String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());

if (path.startsWith("/integra/user/admin/") && !user.hasRole(Role.ADMIN)) {
    res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

---

The hardest part is translating this Java model to a sane DB model. There are several different ways depending on the concrete business requirements, each with its own (dis)advantages. Or perhaps you already have a DB model on which you have to base your Java model (thus, you need to design bottom-up)?

Anyway, assuming that you're using JPA 2.0 (your question history at least confirms this) and that you can design top-down, one of the easiest ways would be to map the `roles` property as an [`@ElementCollection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) against an `user_roles` table. As we're using a `Role` enum, a second `role` table isn't necessary. Again, that depends on the concrete functional and business requirements.

In generic SQL terms, the `user_roles` table can look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
    user_id BIGINT REFERENCES user(id),
    role VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, role)
)
```

Which is then to be mapped as follows:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@CollectionTable(name="user_roles", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
@Column(name="role")
private List<Role> roles;
```

That's basically all you'd need to change in your `User` entity.

---

Next to homebrewed authentication (login/logout) and authorization (role checking), there is also Java EE provided [container managed authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) with which you can [login by `j_security_check` or `HttpServletRequest#login()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206911/best-way-for-user-authentication-on-javaee-6-using-jsf-2-0/2207147#2207147), [filter HTTP requests by `<security-constraint>` in `web.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079469/java-ee-login-page-problem/6079648#6079648), [check the logged-in user by `#{request.remoteUser}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374368/how-to-check-if-is-user-logged-in/8375301#8375301) and [its roles by `#{request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524788/how-to-properly-use-isuserinrolerole/6526525#6526525), etc.

Then there are several 3rd party frameworks such as [PicketLink](http://picketlink.org), [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/), [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/), etc. But this is all out of the question :)

Comment: It's good you have mentioned those libraries that do security, AA. :)

Comment: great answer Bauke, I'm gonna try this out! Thanks!

Comment: Seam Security link is broken (it should point to http://www.seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModuleHome.html). And now it seems to have moved to PicketLink http://picketlink.org/