# How to call backing bean constructor/method before every jsf page load?

Tags: java, jsf, session

I have managed bean with session as `managedbean-scope`, now in constructor of the backing bean, am doing some validation, but since the scope of bean is `session` when user first tries to hit `upload` page, am calling constructor of managed bean and doing some validation to see if user has access to upload page or no.

So on first try, am calling constructor and i get validation error message saying that `upload` page is not available for user, but now if i go to any other tab and click back to `upload` page menu tab, that page shows up, how can i change this behavior so that validation is checked on every pageLoad, also I cannot use `managed-scoped` as `request` for the page, coz i need to maintain some information between different requests in same session.

Here is the code:

Backing Bean Constructor:

```
public Upload()
{
    ValidationStatus authorizeBean = validateUSER(user);                
}
```

Faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>fileUpload</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>Upload</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: do add you comments if question is not clear and needs more clarifications.

Comment: Why don't you just use a request scoped bean and from it call a validation method in your session bean? You just will have to call the validateUSER from the request bean.

Comment: @mael: to understand you correctly, are you suggesting of creating one more backing bean and have it's scope as request but then am creating object of session bean, how would having another request bean help in this scenario?

Comment: Create a Request Backing Bean (or View scoped), then annotate a method with @PostConstruct and using a reference (injected) of your session bean to call the authorization method.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? In JSF 2.x there's an easy way using `<f:event>`, but the verbose XML registration of managed bean and using session instead of view scope indicates JSF 1.x.

Comment: After all, if you're already using JSF 2.x, why don't you put the bean in the view scope instead?

Comment: My understanding could be wrong here, but I i put bean in view scoped then will i not lose all information that i have stored in bean if i go to another view and comeback to upload page ?

Comment: @BalusC: View scope seems to have been working for this particular use case, am able to see values in the bean, if i go to another view and comeback to upload page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bean is the wrong place to do this. I would use either a servlet filter or a JSF Phase listener to handle page access.

An example of using a servlet filter to control page access is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516349/jsf-how-control-access-and-rights-in-jsf)

Answer (score -2):

Use `@PostConstruct`

Reference is [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/jhook/archive/2007/05/jsf_12_ri_backi.html).

In your `JSF` backing bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void initIt(){
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp(){
}
```

Comment: OP needs to invoke the method on every request. The `@PostConstruct` is invoked only once directly after bean's construction and all dependency injection. A session scoped bean is constructed only once per session, not on every request.

Comment: @BalusC, I missed the backing bean is `SessionBean`. :)